# Spring Security 4 Not assigning admin role

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to assign the admin role to a user in my web app using spring mvc and spring security 4.  I'm manually assigning the role to the user in the database, and then I'm just trying to access a url in my web app, however I get the 403 error, which would be good if I was just trying to access as a normal user, but I'm using the admin to try to access it.  I'll show some of my code and see if anyone can see what I'm leaving out.  Thanks in advance.

Here's my User domain object

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

private Long id;

@Size(min=4, max=30)
private String username;

private String password;

private String email;

private University university;

private Set<Course> courses = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSets = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<Post> posts = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<Comment> comments = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<Authorities> authorities = new HashSet<>();

public User () {}

public User(User user) {
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public CharSequence setPassword(String password) {
    return this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
public University getUniversity() {
    return university;
}

public void setUniversity(University university) {
    this.university = university;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<QuestionAnswerSet> getQuestionAnswerSets() {
    return questionAnswerSets;
}

public void setQuestionAnswerSets(Set<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSets) {
    this.questionAnswerSets = questionAnswerSets;
}
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}
public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(Set<Authorities> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public static User createUser(String username, String email, String password) {
    User user = new User();

    user.username = username;
    user.email = email;
    user.password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);

    return user;
}

public User(Long id, String username, String password, String email, University university,
        Set<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSets, Set<Post> posts, Set<Comment> comments, Set<Authorities> authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.university = university;
    this.questionAnswerSets = questionAnswerSets;
    this.posts = posts;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public User(UserDetails userDetails) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

Here's my authorities object.  In my database I have the id as "1" the authority as "ADMIN", and the user as "1", which corresponds with the first user I have entered into the database.

```
@Entity
public class Authorities implements GrantedAuthority {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2848940318555407665L;
private Long id;
private User user;
private String authority;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@ManyToOne
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}
public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}
}
```

My WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static PasswordEncoder encoder;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/register", "/courses", "/editCourse", "/sets", "/search", "/viewCourse/{courseId}", "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf","/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff", "/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2", "/viewCourse/post/{postId}", "/courseSearch", "/setSearch").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/createCourse", "/addUniversities").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http
    .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
         .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/loggedout")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);


}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception  {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    if(encoder == null) {
        encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    return encoder;
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() 
{ 
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository(); 
    repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
    return repository; 
}
}
```

Custom User Details

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails{

private User user;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2020921373107176828L;

public CustomUserDetails () {}

public CustomUserDetails (User user) {
    super(user);
}

@Override
public Set<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
    return super.getAuthorities();
}
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

And my UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

private UserRepository userRepo;

@Transactional
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.example.domain.User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

    CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user);
    customUserDetails.setUser(user);

    return customUserDetails;
}

@Autowired
public void setUserRepo(UserRepository userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasAuthority()` instead of `hasRole()` if your database entry is just "ADMIN".

If you want to use `hasRole` you should change the database entry to "ROLE_ADMIN"